# Matrices that are similar to their negatives

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ is $3 \times 3$ matrix with complex entries such that $A$ is conjugate to $-A$. What are the possible Jordan forms of $A$?

The solution I could come up with is not ingenious: Let $E_{A} = \{\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}, \lambda_{3}\}$ be the set of eigenvalues of $A$. Then $E_{-A} = \{-\lambda_{1}, -\lambda_{2}, -\lambda_{3} \}$. $A$ being similar to $-A$ implies $\text{Tr}(A) = \text{Tr(-A)} \implies \text{Tr}(A) =0$ and we also get that $\det A = 0$ by similarity of $A$ and $-A$ and since $3$ is odd. But $\det A =0 \implies \lambda_{1} = 0$ so that $\text{Tr}(A) =0 \implies \lambda_{2} = -\lambda_{3}$.

Case 1: If any two or all three eigenvalues are the same, then they are all zeros, which gives $C_{A}(x) =x^{3}$ which gives three possible invariant factors: $\{x, x, x\}, \{x, x^{2}\}, \{x^{3} \}$.

Case 2: If the eigenvalues are all distinct, then $C_{A}(x) = x(x-\lambda_{3})(x+\lambda_{3})$ and the Jordan form is just the diagonal matrix.

Oops this wasn't that ugly a solution. I am definitely mistaken and the brutal one is likely to be problem of finding all Jordan forms for $A$ when $A$ is similar to $A^{2}$, which I have posted on a new thread.

Comment: What is the relationship between the eigenvalues of $A$ and $-A$? Conjugate/similar matrices have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: Oh no. I can solve the problem completely myself through a brute force. If your solution is along the lines of your comment then please it is the same approach I have.

Comment: I will just write out my solution so that I don't get a duplicate of a similar answer:-)

Comment: Please do that, because I'm not sure if we are on the same wavelength here.

Comment: It is done as requested.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't see an answer.

Comment: If mine is incorrect, then please write out yours for I will definitely benefit from such a correction.